# Cannot get touchevent from Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, overlay

I'm having some issues registering when somebody has touched somewhere on the map.

I have this source

```
public class GMapsActivity extends MapActivity {

private MapView mapView;

private static final int latitudeE6 = 37985339;
private static final int longitudeE6 = 23716735;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);       
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    CustomItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitudeE6, longitudeE6);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hello", "I'm in Athens, Greece!");

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
    //mapOverlays.add(TouchOverlay);

    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

    mapController.animateTo(point);
    mapController.setZoom(6);

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}


class MapOverlap extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {
       if (event.getAction() == 1){
          GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels( (int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6 + "," + p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       return false;
    }
    }
```

}

And CustomItemizedOverlay

```
public class CustomItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

private Context context;

public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
      super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
}

public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
      this(defaultMarker);
      this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return mapOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mapOverlays.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mapOverlays.get(index);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
    dialog.show();
    return true;
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mapOverlays.add(overlay);
    this.populate();
}
```

}

I added in the (yet it doesn't seem to do anything)

```
class MapOverlap extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {
   if (event.getAction() == 1){
      GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels( (int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6 + "," + p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   return false;
}
```

Have I implemented the class correctly? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you getting any error? If yes than please add the error log so its easy to resolve.......

Answer (score 0):

In your second constructor, you are missing this line of code:

```
super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
```

Instead of:

```
this(defaultMarker);
```

Comment: Thank you, but this hasn't changed anything. The code that isn't working correctly is at the bottom of my file file, the 'onTouchEvent'